# Как поставить lamp server на Убунту 11,04?

Tags: apache, php, ubuntu, mysql

Делал командой `sudo apt-get install tasksel`

Выдало мне

> `Чтение списков пакетов... Готово
> Построение дерева зависимостей       
> Чтение информации о состоянии... Готово
> Будут установлены следующие дополнительные пакеты:
>   aptitude libboost-iostreams1.42.0 libcwidget3 tasksel-data
> Предлагаемые пакеты:
>   aptitude-doc-en aptitude-doc debtags libcwidget-dev
> НОВЫЕ пакеты, которые будут установлены:
>   aptitude libboost-iostreams1.42.0 libcwidget3 tasksel tasksel-data
> обновлено 0, установлено 5 новых пакетов, для удаления отмечено 0 пакетов, и 214 пакетов не обновлено.
> Необходимо скачать 2 854 kБ архивов.
> После данной операции, объём занятого дискового пространства возрастёт на 8 950 kB.
> Хотите продолжить [Д/н]? Д
> Получено:1 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty/main libboost-iostreams1.42.0 i386 1.42.0-4ubuntu2 [55,5 kB]
> Получено:2 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty/main libcwidget3 i386 0.5.16-3ubuntu2 [424 kB]
> Получено:3 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty/main aptitude i386 0.6.3-3.2ubuntu1 [2 332 kB]                                 
> Получено:4 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty/main tasksel-data all 2.88ubuntu3 [8 580 B]                                  
> Получено:5 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty/main tasksel all 2.88ubuntu3 [33,6 kB]                                       
> Получено 2 854 kБ за 6мин 13с (7 638 Б/c)                                                                                          
> Предварительная настройка пакетов ...
> Выбор ранее не выбранного пакета libboost-iostreams1.42.0.
> (Чтение базы данных ... на данный момент установлено 131140 файлов и каталогов.)
> Распаковывается пакет libboost-iostreams1.42.0 (из файла .../libboost-iostreams1.42.0_1.42.0-4ubuntu2_i386.deb)...
> Выбор ранее не выбранного пакета libcwidget3.
> Распаковывается пакет libcwidget3 (из файла .../libcwidget3_0.5.16-3ubuntu2_i386.deb)...
> Выбор ранее не выбранного пакета aptitude.
> Распаковывается пакет aptitude (из файла .../aptitude_0.6.3-3.2ubuntu1_i386.deb)...
> Выбор ранее не выбранного пакета tasksel-data.
> Распаковывается пакет tasksel-data (из файла .../tasksel-data_2.88ubuntu3_all.deb)...
> Выбор ранее не выбранного пакета tasksel.
> Распаковывается пакет tasksel (из файла .../tasksel_2.88ubuntu3_all.deb)...
> Обрабатываются триггеры для man-db ...
> Настраивается пакет libboost-iostreams1.42.0 (1.42.0-4ubuntu2) ...
> Настраивается пакет libcwidget3 (0.5.16-3ubuntu2) ...
> Настраивается пакет aptitude (0.6.3-3.2ubuntu1) ...
> update-alternatives: используется`/usr/bin/aptitude-curses' для предоставления `/usr/bin/aptitude' (aptitude) в автоматический режим.
> Настраивается пакет tasksel-data (2.88ubuntu3) ...
> Настраивается пакет tasksel (2.88ubuntu3) ...
> Обрабатываются триггеры для libc-bin ...
> ldconfig deferred processing now taking place`

Но я что-то не понял, а где php и все остальное? Где папка для работы с документами? Вроде же должна она быть www...

Comment: а sudo apt-get install apache2 php mysql уже не катит?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не торопите события. Поставили tasksel, и запустите его:

```
sudo tasksel
```

Там уже выбирайте `lamp-server`.

Или сразу:

```
sudo tasksel install lamp-server
```